# Can I regain signing authority of a wallet that was drained? Still have Private Key & Passphrase

Tags: solana-program, wallet

After a wallet drain, the hacker was able to change the signing authority on my wallet. I still have the private key and passphrase. I can still import the wallet, but I can no longer sign any transactions to send my NFTs or LP tokens to a new wallet.

Any help appreciated. Wallet address: G7m2vVyh4foQEaZybf2fPXPaQjhPP8DX2oms2CmNV2gA

See transactions below:

https://solscan.io/tx/3k7eQmGRAMomKeKKmSswSuVwfUs8BZvttaWyYTiDpYDpmyesC7YRLYYWvPfGk1wZLm6ndmTXy5ibdL6Qxu987a3H

https://solscan.io/tx/4BWxfaUKTBX5emodHGtHnfm6TtB6VYu9FAe3xcqCQyk8Wto2Ho63CybCQCQvNTibiWJfiYppn5H3DKZcAC1YXJ8o

https://solscan.io/tx/4NiorFaA3YjvthtsWVasyt4r24VhCMqLJmcNeS8D5PbCQwuEhspWMB9dvXtHTzDzRnVv7G1rAwvsMFyED1GeMePD

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Everything that was transfered out of your wallet you will not be able to get back. If the scammer delegated your token accounts you may be able to revoke the delegate with a tool like this: https://famousfoxes.com/revoke Use at your own risk. Its build by famous fox federation. Try transfer everything out of that wallet and then dont use it anymore.

There is some thing your can recover with SolAndys recovery tool:
https://x.com/HeyAndyS/status/1761199502978142568?s=20

Comment: Hi @Jonas H., The revoker doesn't allow me to revoke the NFTs as they are staked. I can't unstake as my wallet can't sign any transactions. Thanks for trying to help. I need a way to change the signing authority on the wallet with the private key and pass phrase.

Comment: A wallet can always sign transactions, it's impossible for someone else to revoke your ability to use a private key or seed phrase entirely. They can only change the authorization for accounts that hold SPL tokens or NFTs that were owned by that wallet.

If you were drained, you may have zero SOL in that wallet. You need at least 0.000005 SOL to pay the transaction fee when signing. Transferring SOL to that wallet would let you or anyone else with the keys sign transactions for that wallet.

Going to add a second comment with a caution about accounts, please read it before unstaking.

Comment: There are two accounts that matter - an account holding the NFT while staked, and an account it returns to in your wallet when unstaked. During drains, the "empty" account in your wallet associated with that NFT often has the ownership changed to the drainer so that if you unstake, they are the only ones who can transfer the NFT. To avoid this you should close the empty token account before unstaking (use a tool like solincinerator) so that a fresh account for the NFT is created when you unstake.

This only applies to custodial staking (NFT leaves your wallet), not noncustodial "freezing".

Comment: Check out SolAndys recovery tool: https://x.com/HeyAndyS/status/1761199502978142568?s=20 It lets you recovery many assets that are not native sol.